# Issue while binding to a selectionchanged command for GridView using MVVM

Tags: gridview, mvvm, using

I am using MVVM model for my application. I have 2 Views that contains a GridView each. Both of them are binding to the same command in the ViewModel for GridView's selection changed.

```
<GridControl Grid.Row="0"
             Grid.Column="1"
             x:Name="TaskItemsGridView"
             SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding ShowSelectedTaskCommand}"
             ItemsSource="{Binding ActiveTaskList, Mode=TwoWay}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding ActiveTask, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

ShowSelectedTaskCommand is invoking a function that performs some functions and updates ActiveTask.

I am facing two issues here.

a) I need to do an additional db save after which the ActiveTask will be set , when  selection changed command is invoked from View1. My issue is even if I make the commands separate to handle this situation, both the commands are executed as I need to update ActiveTask in between. So if one command updates ActiveTask, it will fire SelectionChanged for other command. How can i tackle this situation.
b) Since both functions are called in both cases, how can I add some condition to perform db save.

Below is my func for reference

```
private void ShowSelectedTask()
    {
        if (ActiveTask.EventId != TaskId && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ActiveTaskName))
            UpdateTaskInformation(TaskId); // It updates ActiveTask

          // TO DO: DB save to be performed if this command is invoked from View1.

        if (ActiveTask != null)
        {
            TaskId = ActiveTask.EventId;
            ....

        }
    }
```

Note: The only difference in the functionalities from both the view is the additional db save. Rest of the code are common for both

Comment: A quick and dirty might be to utilize the `SelectionChangedCommandParameter` on the 1 view that performs an additional action (a true/false to _do this_)

Comment: I have already used a CommandParameter to achieve another functionality.So I hope we can't go through that method.